# Find a correct CD/DVD block device on CentOS 7.5

Tags: virtualbox, centos7

I'm on a CentOS 7.5 (GUI less) server (created using Vagrant and Virtualbox ...).

The complet version is the follow ...

[image]

I need to create a mount point and so I've to find the correct cd/dvd block device ... using the `blkid` command I obtain as result the following ...

[image]

The `/dev` directory cointains ..

[image]

Should I use `/dev/sd1` or `/dev/sda2`' Which ones?

My final goal is to install Virtualbox Guest Additions on CentOS via command line ...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: if you've inserted the guest additions CD then the output of "mount" command may be useful to you as well...in general questions like this probably belong more in superuser than SO FWIW...

Comment: I'm trying to follow this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18435/how-to-install-virtualbox-guest-additions-on-centos-via-command-line-only (first answer ..), but when I've to execute `mount /dev/scd0 /media/cdrom` in my casae I don't know what I've to use instead of `/dev/scd0` ...

Comment: You need to select "Devices->install guest additions cd image" from the virtualbox menu of the running VM. Then you run the 3 commands "mount /dev/cdrom /mnt" "cd /mnt/" "./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run" . This requires that you have added a CDROM device to the VM before it is started.

Comment: How may I add a CDROM device to my VM?